# mysql update geo point

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geometry

I have a MySQL table with latitude and longitude values. I want to play around with the spatial stuff in MySQL 5, just to see how it works.

However, I'm having a real problem just getting the point data created from existing values.  I was trying something like this, but it fails with syntax errors in every format I've tried. Can someone point out the right way to do this?

```
UPDATE locationtable a SET geopoint = GeomFromText( POINT() a.latitude a.longitude ) WHERE 1
```

I've also tried other variations, including:

```
UPDATE locationtable a SET geopoint = GeomFromText( 'POINT()' a.latitude a.longitude ) WHERE 1

UPDATE locationtable a SET geopoint = GeomFromText( 'POINT() a.latitude a.longitude' ) WHERE 1
```

And others…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean to do this?:

```
UPDATE locationtable AS a
SET a.geopoint = POINT( a.latitude, a.longitude )
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks ypercube. I was just using the `GeomFromText` since that's what I'd seen in all the demos. Didn't know I could just set a point that way.

Comment: You could also use `geopoint = GeomFromText( CONCAT('POINT(', a.latitude, ' ', a.longitude, ')' ))` but I don't see any reason for such complication in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE locationtable a SET geopoint = GeomFromText( 'POINT(a.latitude a.longitude)' ) WHERE 1
```

Comment: hmmm-- no errors, but it says 0 rows updated with this approach.

Comment: Try removing the `WHERE 1` part

Comment: @julio It's a dumb question, but are you sure the table has data in it?

Comment: Hi Dor, yes, there is data in the table. :)

Comment: @julio in that case I'm sorry, but I have no idea