# Geolocation MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I run a geolocation-based social network.  Members can see other members based on how close they are.

Right now my MySQL query looks like:

```
$lat_min = $geo['user_lat'] - 5;
$lat_max = $geo['user_lat'] + 5;
$long_min = $geo['user_long'] - 5;
$long_max = $geo['user_long'] + 5;    

$members_query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM members WHERE (user_lat BETWEEN " . $lat_min . " AND " . $lat_max . " AND user_long BETWEEN " . $long_min . " AND " . $long_max . ") OR (gc_lat BETWEEN " . $lat_min . " AND " . $lat_max . " AND gc_long BETWEEN " . $long_min . " AND " . $long_max . ")";
```

`user_lat` and `user_long` are coordinates based on geolocation if they have it turned on in their browser.  `gc_lat` and `gc_long` and coordinates based on their IP address.  These rows are all indexed in the database. I am pulling all members within 10 degrees.

The problem is this query takes about 2 seconds to perform for our 250,000+ members, and we want the site to scale.

**ATTEMPT 2:** I have tried assigning quadrants to each member e.g. "36x-99" ... I am rounding off the latitude and longitude to the nearest multiple of 3 to label the quadrant, and then I only pull quadrants within 12 degrees of the quadrant the member is in.

```
$members_query = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM members WHERE quadrant IN ('36x-99', '33x-99', '30x-99', ...);
```

This gave me no noticeable difference in query speed.

Anyone have any ideas of what I should do?  I need to find a solution that will allow the site to scale better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the way you are storing data in the database is not suited for the type of task you are performing.  Using `Point` values in `Geometry` data points is the way to go.  Actually coded something 4+ years back for this purpose, but having issues finding it. But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points) seems to cover it well.

**EDIT** Okay, found my old code, but it’s referring to old client data that I obviously cannot share. But the key to speed with coordinates in databases is using `POINT` data stored in the database table with the type of `GEOMETRY`. [More details here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-wkt-format.html) on the official MySQL site. Since I have needed a reason to revisit this type of code—and the concepts—for a while here is a quick MySQL script I whipped up to create a sample table with sample data to convey the basic concepts. Once you understand what is happening, it opens up lots of cool options.

Also found [this great/simple explanation](http://www.tech-problems.com/calculating-distance-in-mysql-using-spatial-point-type/) of the concept as well.

And found [another great assessment of spatial data](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/) in MySQL 5.6. Lots of great info on indexes & performance. Specifically regarding MySQL spatial index performance:

> **MyISAM tables support Spatial indexes**, so the above queries will use those indexes.

And on the other side of that:

> The **InnoDB engine does not support spatial indexes**, so those queries will be slow.

And here is my basic MySQL testing scripts to help illustrate the concept:

```
/* Create the database `spatial_test` */
CREATE DATABASE `spatial_test` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

/* Create the table `locations` in `spatial_test` */
CREATE TABLE `spatial_test`.`locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coordinates` point NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `idx_coordinates` (`coordinates`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/* Insert some test data into it. */
INSERT INTO `spatial_test`.`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(27.174961 78.041822)'));
INSERT INTO `spatial_test`.`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(27.985818 86.923596)'));
INSERT INTO `spatial_test`.`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(44.427963 -110.588455)'));
INSERT INTO `spatial_test`.`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(19.896766 -155.582782)'));
INSERT INTO `spatial_test`.`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(40.748328 -73.985560)'));
INSERT INTO `spatial_test`.`locations` (`id`, `coordinates`) VALUES (NULL, GeomFromText('POINT(40.782710 -73.965310)'));

/* A sample SELECT query that extracts the 'latitude' & 'longitude' */
SELECT x(`spatial_test`.`locations`.`coordinates`) AS latitude, y(`spatial_test`.`locations`.`coordinates`) AS longitude FROM `spatial_test`.`locations`;

/* Another sample SELECT query calculates distance of all items in database based on GLength using another set of coordinates. */
SELECT GLength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(GeomFromText(astext(PointFromWKB(`spatial_test`.`locations`.`coordinates`))), GeomFromText(astext(PointFromWKB(POINT(40.782710,-73.965310))))))) AS distance
FROM `spatial_test`.`locations`
;

/* Yet another sample SELECT query that selects items by using the Earth’s radius. The 'HAVING distance < 100' equates to a distance of less than 100 miles or kilometers based on what you set the query for. */
/* Earth’s diameter in kilometers: 6371 */
/* Earth’s diameter in miles: 3959 */
SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(40.782710)) * cos(radians(x(`spatial_test`.`locations`.`coordinates`))) * cos(radians(y(`spatial_test`.`locations`.`coordinates`)) - radians(-73.965310)) + sin(radians(40.782710)) * sin(radians(x(`spatial_test`.`locations`.`coordinates`))))) AS distance 
FROM `spatial_test`.`locations`
HAVING distance < 100
ORDER BY id
;
```

Comment: OK, I will look into this.

Comment: Seems like you are on the right track here. I will have to figure this out tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! That helps immensely. I'm trying it now.

Comment: The only thing I'm wondering is will it calculate the distance around the earth, or is it cutting through the earth?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if it's cutting through the earth as long as it's quick. I can use the Haversine formula in the PHP, like I am currently doing, to calculate the actual distance.

Comment: I got my coordinates in the database with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954417/mysql-update-geo-point

Comment: It looks like you have one too many closing parens on the Earth diameter based query. It's also returning me negative values for distance.

Comment: Yes, it is working now! I did convert the table to MyISAM and put a spatial index on the coordinates. Now this query is no longer coming up in my slow queries log. Thanks so much for your help!