# Node.js: Find Nearby Events

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, geocoding

We have a Node.js with MySQL.

In the database we store Longitude, Latitude, and the street addresses of all the events (concerts & comedy shows) happening all over the U.S.

Scenario:  When a User logs in, based on their current location (Longitude and Latitude), I'd like to provide a list of all the events taking place within their 30 mile radius.  What's the best practice to provide such setup with Node.js and MySQL?

**Edit**

i.e.
If I have a database of 10,000 locations (Lat & Lng), what's the best way to calculate which of these locations are in within 30miles radius of a given location.

Comment: @JakeGould  Thank you for the guidance.  If you want to put that in an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad & unspecific. But I provided a very detailed answer as to how to calculate distances with MySQL using `POINT` & `GEOMETRY` functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865747/geolocation-mysql-query/20865855#20865855). More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-wkt-format.html) on the official MySQL site.